# rbind calendar data from Web - list error

Tags: r, list, rbind

I am trying to import calendar dates in R. 
I found a website with dates that I imported with `XML`.

```
library('XML')
u="http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?year=2015&country=5&typ=0&display=2&cols=0&hol=0&cdt=1&holm=1&df=1"

tables = readHTMLTable(u)
```

Get rid of some unecessary elements

```
tables = tables[-1]
tables = tables[-1]
tables = tables[-13]
```

Generate list names

```
names(tables) <- paste('month', 1:12, sep = '')
```

with [a solution proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404877/adding-a-new-column-to-each-element-in-a-list-of-tables-or-data-frames)

```
mtables = mapply(cbind, tables, 'Month'= 1:12, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Here when I want to `rbind` my list:

```
do.call('rbind', mtables)
```

I get an error:

> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
>     names do not match previous names

Could you help with solve this error problem ?

Comment: @PierreLafortune - it does not work to reproduce the example ?

Answer (score 1):

rbind normally takes two parameters.
here is a code snippet using rbind.
hope this helps.
cheers
oliver

```
vehicles1 <- unique(grep("Vehicles", SCC$EI.Sector, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)) 
vehicles <- SCC[SCC$EI.Sector %in% vehicles1, ]["SCC"]

# Select observations relating to Baltimore MD
vehiclesBaltimore <- NEI[NEI$SCC %in% vehicles$SCC & NEI$fips == "24510",]

# Select observations relating to Los Angeles County CA
vehiclesLosAngelesCounty <- NEI[NEI$SCC %in% vehicles$SCC & NEI$fips == "06037",]

# Merge observations of Baltimore and Los Angeles County
vehiclesCompare <- rbind(vehiclesBaltimore, vehiclesLosAngelesCounty)
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I found the issue - it was `header == F`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually in the `header`.

```
`tables = readHTMLTable(u, header = F)`
```

instead of

```
`tables = readHTMLTable(u, header = T)`
```

In order to get the same column names for each lists.

Thanks