# Dataframe name to column in list of dataframes using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of data frames that are imported from excel files. Each file is imported and named after the batch they represent.

Below is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
batch_1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3,
                      B = 4:6)
batch_2 <- data.frame(A = 1:3,
                      B = 4:6)
batch_3 <- data.frame(A = 1:3,
                      B = 4:6)
my_list <- list(batch_1, batch_2, batch_3)
```

I now want to create a new column in each of the data frames that is the name of each data frame.

So it will for each data frame look something like:

```
  A B   batch
1 1 4 batch_1
2 2 5 batch_1
3 3 6 batch_1
```

which I will then combine to one data frame in order to plot.
I can do it manually by `mutate(batch = deparse(substitute(batch_1)))` but I'm struggeling with "purrr-ifying" this.

`map(my_list, ~mutate(batch = deparse(substitute(.x))))`

gives an error:
Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

It does not have to be purrr specific, any method is welcomed.

EDIT:
@user63230 solution works. But, as is typical, you find a solution when you already have one!

An alternative solution for this case is found in the later combination of data frames into one.

`bind_rows(my_list, .id = "batch")` will added, an id column with the name of the data frame.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404877/adding-a-new-column-to-each-element-in-a-list-of-tables-or-data-frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way is to use `lst` instead of `list` which automatically names the list for you with `imap` which uses these names directly (`.y`).

```
library(tidyverse)
my_list <- lst(batch_1, batch_2, batch_3)
purrr::imap(my_list, ~mutate(.x, batch = .y))

# $batch_1
#   A B   batch
# 1 1 4 batch_1
# 2 2 5 batch_1
# 3 3 6 batch_1

# $batch_2
#   A B   batch
# 1 1 4 batch_2
# 2 2 5 batch_2
# 3 3 6 batch_2

# $batch_3
#   A B   batch
# 1 1 4 batch_3
# 2 2 5 batch_3
# 3 3 6 batch_3
```

Comment: This got me almost all of the way. I unfortunately create my list via first `temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")` and then `my_files <- lapply(temp, read_excel)`.
This doesn't include the data frame name like `lst()` does.

Comment: Nevermind! `names(my_files) <- temp` names them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer using `base` and `plyr` would be,

```
#import all batch dataframes 
df= mget(grep(pattern = "bat", x = ls(), value = TRUE))

#convert the list to dataframe
df = ldply(df, as.data.frame)
```